# Proofs with inequalities

Tags: analysis, inequality

I am asked to prove the following, given that $a<b$, and $c<d$, such that $a,b,c,d>0$:

> (1) $a+c<b+d$
>
> (2) $ac<bd$

I have been struggling with these kinds of questions in my course, and am also wondering if there's a good way to approach these kinds of questions.

Comment: Depending on what type of course you are taking, answers to this question will be very different. Can you tell us a little more about it? Perhaps a course title, or if you have an example of a solution your instructor liked...?

Comment: It's more of just a first course in proofs than in analysis, though part of a proof-based course, I think, would involve some analysis.

Comment: Well it looks like it got sorted out. Quantincbolt's answer is exactly what I would have put. Good stuff.

Answer (score 3):

We want to show the following two things, (1) $a+c<b+d$, and (2) $ac<bd$.

The first is quite straightforward. First, we add $c$ to $a<b\to a+c<b+c$. Then, add, $b$ to both sides of $c<d\to b+c<b+d$. Hence, we have $$a+c<b+c<b+d\to a+c<b+d,$$ which is what we wanted to show.

For the second part, multiply $a<b$ by $c$. (Granted that $a,b,c,d>0$, we won't worry about reversal of the inequality when multiplying through by them.) We have, $ac<bc$. Then, multiply $c<d$, by $b$. We have $bc<bd$, and so, $$ac<bc<bd\to ac<bd,$$ which is again, what we wanted to show.

It is useful to have a list of fundamental rules next to you when you are approaching questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

assuming $$a+c\geq b+d$$ since $d>c$ we have
$$a+c\ge b+d>b+c$$ from here we get a contradiction since we have $a<b$
the second proof works analogously we assume $$ac\geq bd$$ and $$bd>bc$$ from here we get also $$a>b$$ and this is not possible

Comment: Is there a reason you're using contradiction? It feel like a direct proof is preferable in this simple case.

Comment: i was just an spontaneously idea by me

Comment: +1 I personally think it's nice because it gives OP an option to approach these problems in different ways. Especially useful to have a different perspective as it might come in handy on tests where certain approaches might simplify the problem more than others.

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe I'm just wary because I've seen too many examples of the famous: "Assume $\neg Q$. Now we show $P \rightarrow Q$, thus by contradiction $P \rightarrow Q$", when people get overzealous with contradiction.